Custom button to download a map as an image
My goal is to capture the current state of the map (including the legend) and download it as a PNG image file named "map.png". So, i used the html2canvas library to capture the map as an image first, and then create a download link for it,"downloadBtn", for triggering the download.
The downloaded image file shows a map with no actual map content loaded.
Result :



// Initialize the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
// Add a base layer (e.g., OpenStreetMap)
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);
// Function to generate rainbow color based on a value between 0 and 1
function getRainbowColor(value) {
  var hue = Math.floor((1 - value) * 240); // 240 for blue, 0 for red
  return "hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 50%)"; // Use HSL for hue-based color
}
// Create a custom legend control
var legend = L.control({
  position: 'bottomright'
});
legend.onAdd = function(map) {
  var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend');
  var labels = [];
  var grades = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]; // Define the range for the legend
  // Loop through the grades and generate labels with a rainbow color
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    var color = getRainbowColor(grades[i]);
    div.innerHTML +=
      '<i style="background:' + color + '"></i> ' +
      grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
  }
  return div;
};
// Add the legend to the map
legend.addTo(map);

// Function to download the map as an image
function downloadMap() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('map')).then(function(canvas) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'map.png';
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.click();
  });
}

// Add click event listener to the download button
document.getElementById('downloadBtn').addEventListener('click', downloadMap);
#map {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

.legend {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #555;
}

.legend i {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#downloadBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

<div id="map"></div>
<button id="downloadBtn">Download Map</button>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>




I made you a snippet. It does not work due to security reasons at StackOverflow. A JSFiddle will work: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/v2h9rmdy/

This will help you: https://pasichnykvasyl.github.io/Leaflet.BigImage/
